# Rounding value to 2 decimal place without the use of cout<<

Tags: c++

Hi im trying to convert a value to 2 decimal place. But instead of using setprecision, i want it to be from a string. Does anyone know how to round the value to 2 decimal?

```
double computeArea(){
     double area = 3.1415927 * pow(3,2);
     return area;
}

int main(){
  string circle;
  circle += to_string((double)area);
  cout << circle;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could write to an `ostringstream` and output that to `cout`.

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: `printf ("%.2f\n", computeArea());`?

Comment: std::stringstream ss; ss << std::setprecision(2); ss << whatever; cout << ss.str();

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
double round_to_two_decimals(double value)
{
    return std::floor(100.0 * value) / 100.0;
}

int main() 
{

    double circle = 3.14159279265;

    std::cout << circle << std::endl;
    std::cout << round_to_two_decimals(circle) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this might produce inaccurate results for some numbers

Comment: okay seems I still need more coffee this morning :)
For starters floor should have been std::round... and yeah it was quick and dirty. And I haven't been thinking about potential other corner cases at all.

Comment: One does not do coffee on sundays!